format usb as fat32 or ntfs in android
I have a samsung galaxy a12 android smart phone that I took a few videos with, and a usb with usb c adapter. My tv can play videos from a usb formatted as fat32 or ntfs. My usb is currently formatted as exfat and is empty, so there is no need to worry about backing up files on it. The tv says "you need to plug in the usb before viewing photos" and it is a samsung UA50F5000AM.
Is there a free,libre app for Android that can show me the format and format my usb in one of these two filesystems? I tried searching online yet I do not have root and do not trust proprietary applications - I do not have any guarantee that they will do the job after I purchase them. (MLUSB says I need to buy a exFAT plugin, for example, though I do not even need exfat in the first place.)
I already tried to reboot the tv and it did not help.

Software recommendation requests are off-topic here, but on-topic at Software Recommendations SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Formatting requires access to the block device which means root permissions are required.  If your phone is rooted you can simply use common Linux mkfs commands in termux.
